# Error Utilizing Pytorch Transforms and Custom Dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

This question mainly concerns the return value of `__getitem__` in a `pytorch Dataset` which I've seen as both a tuple and a dict in the source code.

I have been following [this tutorial](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html#dataset-class) for creating a dataset class within my code, which is following [this tutorial](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/transfer_learning_tutorial.html) on transfer learning. It has the following definition of a dataset.

```
class FaceLandmarksDataset(Dataset):
"""Face Landmarks dataset."""

    def __init__(self, csv_file, root_dir, transform=None):
        """
        Args:
            csv_file (string): Path to the csv file with annotations.
            root_dir (string): Directory with all the images.
            transform (callable, optional): Optional transform to be applied
                on a sample.
        """
        self.landmarks_frame = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.landmarks_frame)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir,
                                self.landmarks_frame.iloc[idx, 0])
        image = io.imread(img_name)
        landmarks = self.landmarks_frame.iloc[idx, 1:].as_matrix()
        landmarks = landmarks.astype('float').reshape(-1, 2)
        sample = {'image': image, 'landmarks': landmarks}

        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)

        return sample
```

As you can see, `__getitem__` returns a dictionary with two entries.
In the transfer learning tutorial, the following calls are made to transform a dataset:

```
    data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
    'val': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
}

data_dir = 'hymenoptera_data'
image_datasets = {x: datasets.ImageFolder(os.path.join(data_dir, x),
                                          data_transforms[x])
                  for x in ['train', 'val']}
dataloaders = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=4,
                                             shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
              for x in ['train', 'val']}
dataset_sizes = {x: len(image_datasets[x]) for x in ['train', 'val']}
class_names = image_datasets['train'].classes

use_gpu = torch.cuda.is_available()

inputs, classes = next(iter(dataloaders['train']))
```

That last line of code causes an error in my code by attempting to run transform on a sample in my custom dataset.

> 'dict' object has no attribute 'size'

But if the tutorial dataset is implemented correctly, shouldn't it function correctly with a transform? My own hybrid implementation is below:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.optim import lr_scheduler
from torch.autograd import Variable
import numpy as np
import torchvision
from torchvision import datasets, models, transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import os
import copy
from torch.utils.data import *
from skimage import io, transform
plt.ion()


class NumsDataset(Dataset):
    """Face Landmarks dataset."""

    def __init__(self, root_dir, transform=None):
        """
        Args:
            csv_file (string): Path to the csv file with annotations.
            root_dir (string): Directory with all the images.
            transform (callable, optional): Optional transform to be applied
                on a sample.
        """
        self.docs = []
        for file in os.listdir(root_dir):
            #print(file)
            if file.endswith(".txt"):
                path = os.path.join(root_dir, file)
                with open(path, 'r') as f:
                    self.docs.append( (  file , list(f.read()) ) ) #tup containing file, image values pairs
        self.root_dir = root_dir
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self): #returns number of images
        i = 0
        for j in self.docs:
            i += len(j[1])
        return i

    def len2(self): #returns number of batches
        return len(self.docs)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        idx1 = idx // self.len2()
        idx2 = idx % self.len2()
        imglabel = self.docs[idx1][0] #label with filename for batch error calculation later
        imgdir = os.path.join(self.root_dir, self.docs[idx1][0].strip(".txt"))
        img = None
        l = idx2

        for file in os.listdir(imgdir):
            file = os.path.join(imgdir, file)
            if(l == 0):
                img = io.imread(file)
            l -= 1
        sample = (img , imglabel)
        sample ={'image': img, 'label': imglabel}
        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)

        return sample




data_transforms = {
    'train': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
    'val': transforms.Compose([
        transforms.Resize(256),
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
    ]),
}
data_dir = "images"
image_datasets = {x: NumsDataset(os.path.join(data_dir, x),
                                          data_transforms[x])
                  for x in ['train', 'val']}
dataloaders = {x: torch.utils.data.DataLoader(image_datasets[x], batch_size=5) 
              for x in ['train', 'val']}

dataset_sizes = {x: len(image_datasets[x]) for x in ['train', 'val']}
class_names = ["one", "two", "four"]

use_gpu = torch.cuda.is_available()
# Get a batch of training data
inputs, classes = next(iter(dataloaders['train']))
```

directory structure:

```
images
     /train
        /file1
            *.jpg
        /file2...
            *.jpg
        file1.txt
        file2.txt...
     /val
        /file1
            *.jpg
        /file2...
            *.jpg
        file1.txt
        file2.txt...
```

Is the sample I'm returning formatted incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The particular way the tutorial on dataloading uses the custom dataset is with self defined transforms. The transforms must be designed to fit the dataset. As such, the dataset must output a sample compatible with the library transform functions, or transforms must be defined for the particular sample case. Choosing the latter, among other things has resulted in completely functional code.

Answer (score 2):

The below problem occurs when you pass dict instead of image to transforms. The custom transforms mentioned in the example can handle that, but a default transforms cannot, instead you can pass only image to the transform. This will solve half of the problem.

> 'dict' object has no attribute 'size'

the rest of the problem lies with the image handling code in the example, so I had to dig through till transforms.py in the torchvision; this uses PIL image unlike skimage mentioned in the example, so I replaced the code with PIL and is working perfectly fine.

> site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py

**Original Code:**

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
        img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir,self.anb_frame.iloc[idx, 0])
        image = io.imread(img_name)
        labels = self.anb_frame.iloc[idx, 1:]
        labels = np.array([labels])
        sample = {'image': image, 'labels': labels}
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        return sample
```

**Modified:**

```
def __getitem__(self, idx):
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
        img_name = os.path.join(self.root_dir,self.anb_frame.iloc[idx, 0])
        image = Image.open(img_name)
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        labels = self.anb_frame.iloc[idx, 1:]
        labels = np.array([labels])
        sample = {'image': image, 'labels': labels}
        return sample
```